# Does turning back time affect pc

Tags: time

If I were to set the date *back* (**same** year, different month) -- resave a file from its original date (just for the heck of it) -- then set the date **back** to **current**, will that affect anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends what else is running at that time.  I know some databases and licenced tools that get completely messed up and may stop working if you do that.  Best to do something like that on a VM and then copy the file back to your filestore.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to do this

Answer (score 2):

It will not affect anything seriously. With a different time, SSL connections won't be made, but your purpose is not to perform a connection with SSL during the time difference.

That said, there [are tools](https://www.petges.lu) that allow you to just modify the time/date of a file, which is a far easier method to use.